# Expo SDK 38 error: "AR module has been removed from expo package" even though no AR module is usedt

Tags: react-native-ios

[image]

I was trying to run this on iOS simulator but got this error. The app runs fine on android and android simulator though. I did some research and this could be from outdated Expo SDK but mine is SDK 38. This app uses three.js + expo-graphics, not sure if they are related. Any help is appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and until expo-graphics is updated to completely remove the AR package you will need to go into the expo-graphics folder and comment out any line involving AR, including the entirety of the ARCameraState.js and ARRunningState.js files. Hopefully this helps even though it is a very messy solution